# Localized Linear Histogram Match using python

Tags: python, gdal, remote-sensing

I would like to use the local linear histogram match for filling the missing pixels of a Landsat 7 image with another older image ([SLC Gap-Filled Products](http://landsat.usgs.gov/documents/SLC_Gap_Fill_Methodology.pdf)).

Do you have any idea how can I do it by using the gdal commands?